# passing a value from controller to jsp in spring MVC using map

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

i have a controller like this. i want to get this serverIp and port in a jsp which contains a javascript. i tried ${serverIp} and     ${port} but its not working. what exactly to write in jsp

```
public @ResponseBody ModelAndView getControllerAndServer(ModelAndView model,@RequestParam("siteId") Integer siteId) {   


String serverIp= null;
    Integer port = null;
    List<Object[]> serverAndController = controllerDao.getControllerAndServerInfo(siteId);
    Map <String, ControllerDao> map = new HashMap <String, ControllerDao>();


        int i=0;
        Object[] result = serverAndController.get(i);
        if(result!=null)
        {
        serverIp=(String)result[7];
        model.addObject(serverIp);
        port = (Integer)result[8];
        model.addObject(port);

        }
         if(map.containsKey(siteId)){
               map.get(serverIp);
               map.get(port);

        }


    return model;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use the `model.addObject("Key", "value")` method to store that values:

```
   serverIp=(String)result[7];
    model.addObject("serverIp",serverIp);
    port = (Integer)result[8];
    model.addObject("port",port);
```

For more informations see [Javadoc of ModelAndView](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html#addObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-)

Than you can use `${serverIp}` and `${port}` to add it to your view.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. Let me try this.

Comment: that worked. thanks! Sorry for another stupid question.  how to pass this ${serverIp} and ${port} to a javascript function in the same jsp?

Comment: @sangeethanair Try to use it same way